# Auto complete textfield with ExtJs

Tags: javascript, web-applications, autocomplete, extjs

How can I code a simple auto complete feature with ExtJs? If the field has address and they start typing `st` it should become street, etc

Comment: I write this as a comment rather than an answer since I don't have time to give you tested code, just a sketch. It sounds like this can be done with ComboBox with config properties hideTrigger: true (so that it looks like a normal TextField) and typeAhead: true (which provides a mechanism for suggestions), and with a listener for the keyup event, which can then parse the string (getValue()) and see whether the last word matches with some given dictionary and populate the ComboBox with any suggestion(s) accordingly.

Comment: @fastcodejava can u post your completed code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Mitch suggests in his comment, you can use Ext.form.Combobox, properly configured, to do this.  You won't need to bind anything to the keyup event, as Combobox will handle this for you.

Here's the beginning of a config that should work.  You'll need to provide an appropariate Ext.data.Store (or subclass thereof), along with a few other config values (displayField,valueField,queryParam, etc).  All the necessary stuff is pretty well documented in the API docs)

```
MyTypeahead = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
   triggerAction:'all',
   typeAhead:true,
   mode:'remote',
   minChars:2,
   forceSelection:true,
   hideTrigger:true
});
```

Comment: I was under the impression that input like "123 main st" should trigger the suggestion "123 main street" where "street" is in the dictionary but "123 main street" is not; to my knowledge, there is no automatic mechanism in ComboBox for this. Although I've never used queryParam before so I could be wrong. Anyway I gave +1.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read it that way -- my answer is just a simple forced-selection typeahead field.  "123 main st" would suggest "123 main street" iff "123 main street" existed as an option.  queryParam just names the request variable used to make the remote lookup.

Comment: Mitch is right about what I was looking for. I still gave +1 for the effort and accepted the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Here's the example that they have, they call it "[live search](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/forum-search.html)".

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS : How to make combobox perform "Contains"/LIKE search
see [this](http://atechiediary.blogspot.in/2013/06/first-page-extjs-containslike-search-in.html)